# Get previous day data from database based on frequently changing date on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

I have two buttons, Front and Back, and one div :

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

Now when my page load I will display by default previous 24 hours data from a base date.

My Back and Front button:

```
<button type="button" id="btnForward" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Forward</button>

<button type="button" id="btnBack" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Forward</button>
```

when user clicks on back button then I would like to fetch previous 24 hours data and on click of forward button I would like to fetch forward 24 hours data.

- current date on page loads:date should be 26/2/2016 - 25/2/2016
- when user clicks on Back button 1st  time: 25/2/2016 - 24/2/2016
- when user clicks on Back button 2nd time: 24/2/2016 - 23/2/2016
- when user clicks on Forward button 1st time: 25/2/2016 - 24/2/2016
- when user clicks on Forward button 2nd time: 26/2/2016 - 25/2/2016

I also want to prevent dates greater than the base date being returned.

This is my logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        MyFunction(Actions);
    }
    function MyFunction(Actions) {
        // My ajax function call on Controller.
        Parameters:Actions,count
    }
    $("#btnBack").click(function () {
        Actions = "Back";
        count++;
        MyFunction(Actions);
    }); 
    $("#btnForward").click(function () {
        Actions = "Forward";
        // count--;
        MyFunction(Actions);
        // count++;
    });
</script>
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Merge(string actionType=null,int count=0)
{
    var date1 = new DateTime(2016, 2, 26,16,27,57);
    DateTime Start= new DateTime();
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionType))
        {
          date1= date1.AddDays(-(count));
            if (actionType == "Back")
                Start = date1.AddDays(-1);
            else
            {
                Start= date1.AddDays(1);
            }

        }
        else
            Start = date1.AddDays(-1);
    var data = context.MyTable.Where(c => c.Date.Value > Start&& c.Date.Value <= date1);
}
```

In the above code I have successfully managed to get data correctly for back button but now struggling to get data when user clicks on forward button, and then I am not getting correct date.

Comment: Are you trying to get the values for a day, or for the 24 hour period before of after a particular point in time? (its not clear why you use `var date1 = new DateTime(2016, 2, 26,16,27,57);` )

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Consider this as my system date:var date1 = new DateTime(2016, 2, 26,16,27,57);Now when my page loads then i will query previous 24 hours data from this date i.e i want 25/2/2016 and 26/2/2016 data from time 16:27:57 Pm to 16:26:57

Comment: @StephenMuecke:I have use this date because i have data in my table for this date only

Comment: There is no reason to post back a value for `actionType` - all you need in an `int` (which is incremented in the client) and then get you dates relative to your 'base' date - `startDate = date1.AddDays(count); endDate = date1.AddDays(count + 1);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Can you please post solution that will be more better because i need to take care of that as well that i need to disable my forward button when user tried to get data ahead of current system date

Comment: @StephenMuecke:When to do this:startDate = date1.AddDays(count); endDate = date1.AddDays(count + 1);

Comment: I cannot follow the logic - you initially start with `26/2/2016`, but you say clicking the forward button will display `2/2/2016`? And are you trying to prevent getting any dates greater than `26/2/2016`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108164/discussion-between-learning-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller method needs only one parameter, an `int` to indicate the day(s) relative to your base date.

```
public ActionResult Merge(int days)
{
    if (days > 0) // protect against malicious users
    {
        // return an error
    }
    var baseDate = new DateTime(2016, 2, 26,16,27,57);
    DateTime EndDate = baseDate.AddDays(days);
    DateTime StartDate = basedate.AddDays(days - 1)
    var data = context.MyTable.Where(c => c.Date > StartDate && c.Date <= EndDate );
    ....
}
```

Then in the view, initialize a javascript variable for `days` and increment/decrement based on which button is clicked

```
// initially disable the forward button
<button type="button" id="forward" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" disabled="disabled">Forward</button>
<button type="button" id="back" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Back</button>

<script>
    var days = 0;
    var forward = $('#forward');
    $('#forward').click(function() {
        days++;
        if (days == 0) {
            forward.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        // call ajax function and pass value of `days` to the controller
    });
    $('#back').click(function() {
        days--;
        forward.prop('disabled', false);
        // call ajax function and pass value of `days` to the controller
    });
```

Comment: Let me test your code but thank you so much for posting solution

Comment: ok i have tested your solution and it is working totally fine but just wanted to ask you 1 thing that the field on which i am doing comparision is date and values are like this in my tables:2016-02-26 19:34:39.000,2016-02-26 19:34:07.000,2016-02-26 19:33:36.000

Comment: Now if i am saying that from current system date and time like the one i have used:26/2/2012 16:27:57 go and get the 24 hours previous day data from exact this time like from 16:27:57 then should i use this comparision to get exact match with time too:c.Date.Value > Start&& c.Date.Value <= date1

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying that when you first display the data, you want to get the previous 24 hours data from the current date/time (i.e. the time as it is exactly when you hit the controller method)?

Comment: My current system date time is :26/2/2016 16:27:57.Now when i say get previous 24 hours data/forward 24 hours data then during comparision with my database table field i would like to get data from 26/2/2016 16:27:57 to 25/2/2016 16:27:57.So what i mean is that during comparision like this (c.Date > StartDate && c.Date <= EndDate). Will this comparision will take time in to consideration too while comparing with my database table field because my database table field have date and time too as you can see in my above comments or just date like 25/2/2016-26/2/2016 without time consideration???

Comment: It will take the time into consideration.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between this:c.Date.Value  and c.Date??

Comment: If your property is nullable (e.g. `DateTime?`), then you would need `c.Date.Value`, otherwise use `c.Date`

Comment: Yes it is nullable .Excellent sir.thank you so much for all the help